# Write debug.trace message from system.web.dll to file

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a asp.net application and i want catch debug.trace messages from System.Web.dll to file.
So i try to add such section to my web.config file but nothing was happend.

```
<system.diagnostics>  
      <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">  
         <listeners>  
            <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" initializeData="c:\site\app_data\MyListener.log" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, LogicalOperationStack, Timestamp, ThreadId, Callstack, DateTime" />  
         </listeners>  
      </trace>  
   </system.diagnostics>
```

Is it possible at all ?

Note1: i use .net 4.8. I expect that file c:\site\app_data\MyListener.log  appeared with logs but it didn't

Comment: Welcome to SO. A few questions; please [edit] your question with any answers. What do you mean by "nothing happened"? What steps did you take to test it? What version of .NET are you using? See [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can code your own to catch debug.trace messages from System.Web.dll

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
       Trace.AutoFlush = true;
       Trace.Indent();
       Trace.WriteLine("Entering Main");
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
       Trace.WriteLine("Exiting Main");
       Trace.Unindent();
    }
}
```

All thing that you need to do just foolow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=net-5.0)

Comment: may be you can create test project with .net console app and create a new class and pest this code and test.

Comment: i need get trace results for exact application not for test project